# Storing text part of href for use in php

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to store the text part of my href to be used in a query in php. I used the following code to store the text part of another href and it worked fine (the text part was a string from my database):

But the below code to store the href text part which is numbers is not storing for some reason. The alert wont even appear. The 'year' in my database is varchar by the way. code:

```
    <script>
        $(document).on('click', 'person', function(){
        var clicked = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "random.php",
            data: {clicked : clicked},
            success: function(data){
                $("#answer").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I haven't included the php side of the code because I believe i'm going wrong somewhere in the above code? as not even the alert shows up.

Comment: something in the console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the issue is here:

```
$(document).on('click', 'studentyear', function(){
```

your code should be:

```
$(document).on('click', '.studentyear', function(){
```

jQuery uses [CSS Selectors](http://%20-%20%60'.studentyear'%60%20will%20select%20all%20elements%20with%20the%20*studentyear*%20%20%20%20class.) and your code is pointing to a non-existing element with a `<studentyear>` tag

- `'studentyear'` will select *< studentyear >* elements.
- `'.studentyear'` will select all elements with a *studentyear*
  class.
- `'#studentyear'` will select the element with the id *studentyear*.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you